# Picture gets blurred when mobile responsive

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I am doing this [website](https://vibrant-feynman-f007cb.netlify.app/), and the background picture when I see it on my mobile, it gets blurred. Even that in google dev tools if I try the responsive tools, it seems good.
I tried different phones, and they show up blurred also, so it's me the problem :)
This is the code:

```css
  .main {
  /* background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559742811-822873691df8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1534&q=80"); */
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534080564583-6be75777b70a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80");
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  /* background-size: contain; */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #464646;
}
```

I saw it [here](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) and in other places but seems nothing is working. What I am doing wrong here?
Appreciate your help

Comment: how about picture ratio?

Comment: Not really... I am missing something here... And I said it was blurred, but its really zoomed. Basically when in mobile, it shows only a small part of the top of the image..

Comment: I changed the link of the picture for a small width, and took away the background position : https://wizardly-panini-045e19.netlify.app/. It's better, but not clear image...

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with `object-fit` property [w3 link here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp)

Comment: Hi Stelios. Nope, nothing happened. Still trying tough